# Why Islam apparently incorporates stories in the religion which has nothing to do with muslims?

Tags: prophet-isa

Before starting my question, I assume there might be several mistakes in my "knowledge" of Islam so apologies in advance.

If I understand correctly, according to the jewish and muslim traditions, muslims are the descendants of Ishmael son of Abraham and jewishs are the descendants of Isaac son of Abraham. Later in the story, jewishs were expecting a Christ or Messiah, a king that will bring salvation to jewishs and mankind. Christians believe the christ to be Jesus and they also believe him to be the son of god, jewishs believe it wasnt Jesus, and muslims believe the christ was Isa (Jesus) but he wasnt the son of god.

My question is, why muslims incorporate this part of the story of jewishs (the christ) which has nothing to do with muslims? (since muslims are the descendants of Ishmael who wasnt an ancestor of Christ, so this part of the story isnt connected at all with muslims ancestors) . I dont understand this because if muslims believe the ultimate word of god was revealed to them, then why they think god kept a link only with jewishs about Christ,  sending jewishs the Christ.

Comment: Which story are you talking about?

Comment: Please check your spelling the next time a more thoroughly.

Comment: The story mentioned in the precedent paragraph, the story of the jewishs expecting a Christ or Messiah that would bring salvation to them and mankind

Comment: Well in Islam Ishaq or Isaac as you mention it is also a Prophet. So to say that muslims are descendants of only Ismail or Ishmael is false in islamic history.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should look up the definition of muslim. Most dictionaries would give you as an explanation that we are people who believe in the religion of Islam, not descendants of prophets or something like that.

Second of all because we are believers of the Quran, creations of Allah (swa), I'll give you citations from the Quran to back up why it is wrong to say we stem from the Prophet Ishaq (may Allah be please with his deeds), because it's just a part of the genealogy tree we muslims are part of. As I mentioned in my comment above there are also muslims descendants from Ishaq. The moral of this question is not to see muslims necessarily as descendants of Prophets but more as the creations of Allah.

> **Surah As-Zumar Chapter 39:5-6**
>   *He has created you (all) out of one living entity, and out of it fashioned its mate; and he has bestowed upon you four kinds of cattle of either sex; (and) He creates you in your mother’s wombs, one act of creation after another, in threefold depths of darkness. Thus is God, your Sustainer: unto Him belongs all dominion: there is no deity save Him: how, then, can you lose sight of the truth?*

Third of all here is a part of the genealogy tree since Prophet Ibrahim (as).

https://www.whyislam.org/common-ground/family-tree-of-prophets/

Comment: ok, that clarifies a bit that there are also muslims from the Ishaq root. Yet, that doesnt explain why Islam believes Isa is the Christ, if the Christ was supposed to be the the savior of another religion? (the jewishs)

Comment: But the Jewish don't think Jezus is their Christ or Messiah. They're still waiting for him till this day. See this wikipedia article explaining this issue. Note that Judaism is the same as the religion of Jewish people.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism%27s_view_of_Jesus

Comment: I know that the jewishs dont think Isa or Jesus is the Christ, and that they are still  waiting for him. But I dont see how that explains why Islam believes Isa is the Christ, if the Christ was supposed to be the the savior of another religion? (the jewishs)

Comment: Well I our religions have some similarities but that doesn't mean one thing of a religion will automatically have consequences for the other religion.

Comment: @Pablo Islam doesn't say Jesus or Isa (A.S) is the "Christ". In fact, there is no such thing as "Christ" in Islam. His story is mentioned because he was one of the Prophets and also to refute the Christians who take him as son of God.